# Cannot insert into database using vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, project

I've got a problem and I don't know if its the insert query statement or the Database it self.

This is the insert statement.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim value As Integer
    If txtPassword.Text = txtPassCon.Text Then
        Try
            constring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\tmsDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            con = New SqlConnection(constring)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Login (Username,Password) values ('" & txtUsername.Text & "' , '" & txtPassword.Text & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.CommandText = "select max(id) from login"
            value = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Scouts (Name,Club,Email, LoginID) values ('" & txtName.Text & "' , '" & txtClub.Text & "' , '" & txtEmail.Text & "', '" & value & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("Registeration Sucessful")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run this seems to work because it successfully gets to the messagebox and shows me the message but when I check the db to see if its actually saved there, it doesn't show

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Login] (
    [Id]       INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY ,
    [Username] NVARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    [Password] NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

This is the table in the database. set id to Identity because I thought that was how to make an auto number column

Comment: I'd recommend not building your insert statements from strings like this because it opens you up to sql injection attacks. It also fails for names like "Paddy O'Ryan"

Comment: Is there an error message?  What is it?  `it gets to the messagebox` but you have 2.  PLS help us out by reading [Ask] and also take the [Tour].   Also dont concat SQL, use parameters and never ever store passwords as plain text - hash them.  Assigning a unique ID from the count of rows will fail horribly eventually - use the AI PK the DB provides.

Comment: Okay sure taking note of that , but there is no error thrown back. Nothing at all. just doesnt insert into the database

Comment: If there is no error how do you know it is not inserting?  `Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tll you how many rows were affected.  The insert can fail if you try to specify the value for an identity column or if that ID exists which is a real possibility using RowCount as an Id

Comment: So you get the "Registeration successful" message box (should be spelled "Registration", by the way), no error, but you show no rows in the table when you query it in SSMS?  What about the other table (Scouts).  Anything there?

Comment: Is your database file, tmdDB.mdf, part of your project?  If so, what is the setting for the `Copy to Output Folder` set to?

Comment: Okay found the solution , the database was messing up.. the file in the debug folder wasnt responding to change so i deleted it and replaced it with a new one i did. Sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 0):

'Create ExecuteScalar function

```
  Public Function ExecuteScalar(query As String, ByVal ParamArray param() As Object) As int

        Try

            _commanda = New SqlCommand(query, _connection)
            _commanda.CommandTimeout = 200

            _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_commanda)
            _commanda.Transaction = _transaction


            For i = 0 To param.Count - 1

                _commanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, param(i))

            Next

        dim value = _commanda.ExecuteScalar()

            _sqlda.Dispose()
            _commanda.Dispose()

            Return value

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace)

            Return nothing
        End Try


    End Function
```

'Create ExecuteNonQuery function

```
    Public Function ExecuteNonQuery(query As String, ByVal ParamArray param() As Object) As Boolean

        Try

            _commanda = New SqlCommand(query, _connection)
            _commanda.CommandTimeout = 200

            _sqlda = New SqlDataAdapter(_commanda)
            _commanda.Transaction = _transaction


            For i = 0 To param.Count - 1

                _commanda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, param(i))

            Next

            _commanda.ExecuteNonQuery()


            _sqlda.Dispose()
            _commanda.Dispose()

            Return True

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace)

            Return False
        End Try


    End Function
```

'Call it

```
try
 if _connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed then
    _connection.open()
 end if

   if  ExecuteNonQuery("Insert into Login values (@0,@1)",txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text) then

   dim value = ExecuteScalar("select max(id) from login")

  if ExecuteNonQuery("Insert into Scouts (Name,Club,Email, LoginID) values (@0,@1,@2,@3)", txtName.Text , txtClub.Text , txtEmail.Text, value ) then

        _connection.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Registeration Sucessful")

  else

        MessageBox.Show("Registeration Not Sucessful")
  end if

  else 

        MessageBox.Show("Registeration Not Sucessful")
  end if 

  Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace)

  End try
```

Answer (score 0):

It would also help to change the exception to SQLException in the catch block e.g.
 Catch ex As SQLException 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
End Try